# Laravel backend fails when Chrome dev console is open ONLY

Tags: ajax, laravel, google-chrome

I have noticed a really weird Laravel and Chrome bug where any initial API call will fail due to the .env file not loading in time.

I have a view being returned by Laravel with some data however depending on what this user has selected in a drop down will dynamically change the proceeding options in the following drop downs, i.e. When the page firsts loads there will be an auto selected initial option in the first drop down, I then make the AJAX call to populate the following drop downs.

This works perfectly each time but ONLY if the Chrome developers console is closed. If I then have the developer console open and say I'm looking at the network tab, the initial api call (via AJAX) fails and says that the .env variables aren't correct for my backend (they're all null as if it hasn't been able to load them in time).

Is there any known issue of this sort between Chrome/Laravel/AJAX? I find it super weird that this only happens when my Chrome developers console is open.

**I.e:**

> message: "Argument 1 passed to Akeneo\Pim\ApiClient\AkeneoPimClientBuilder::__construct() must be of the type string, null given

Comment: How do you know that this error is not thrown when you don't have the console open? does something on the page not work when the console is open?

Comment: The fields correctly populate when the console is closed, but when open I get an error in network tab + no fields are populated.